# Firebase, Realtime database отслеживать изменения в фоне Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, workmanager

Что мне использовать для отслеживания изменений в базе данных в фоновом режиме на android (kotlin)?
Например при изменение значения в базе с 0 на 1 я хочу чтобы на смартфоне открылось мое приложение и начало проигрывать звук (типа сигнализации), есть Firebase JobDispatcher но пишут что он устарел и надо использовать workManager, workManager насколько я понял из описания будет выполняться в порядке какой то очереди и не сработает сразу при изменение в базе данных.
Посоветуйте в какую сторону смотреть пожалуйста.

Comment: В целом задача почти не решаема из-за ограничений ОС на фоновые процессы. Телефон может быть в Doze режиме и никаких соединений с сервером не держать. Приемлемым максимумом может быть запуск постоянной фоновой службы (Foreground Service) с неубиваемым уведомлением в шторке - будет работать более-менее постоянно (учитывайте постоянно меняющиеся требования гугла к тому как это должно работать). Ну или рутуйте девайс, правьте конфиги ОС и делайте вообще что угодно)

Comment: Благодарю! Тоже к такому выводу пришел, но так как не давно в андроид разработке то подумал что чего то не знаю.